# Integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx e^{-nx^2/2}(z-ix)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, contour-integration

$$
I\equiv\mathcal{F}_n(z)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx e^{-nx^2/2}(z-ix)^n.
$$
Evaluate I for $n \to \infty$ and z real. We can consider $z\geq 0$ due to the symmetry of $\mathcal{F}$ given by
$$
\mathcal{F}_n(-z)=(-1)^n\mathcal{F}_n(z).
$$
I am looking for a solution, thanks.

Comment: Shot in the dark here, but when you see $e^{-x^2}$, that's often a clue that saddle point integration is called for.

Comment: @bob.sacamento I agree, maybe that is a good solution to post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach. Recalling the binomial theorem, we have

> $$ I = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n\choose k}i^kz^{n-k} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^ke^{-nx^2/2} dx,  $$

which can be evaluated to

> $$ = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(  ( -1 ) ^{k}+1 ) {n\choose k}i^k n^{-\frac{k}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}\,{2}^{\frac{k}{2}-\frac{1}{2}}  z^{n-k}\,\Gamma\left( \frac{k}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \right),\quad i=\sqrt{-1} $$

**Note:** To evaluate the integral

> $$F =  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^ke^{-nx^2/2} dx,  $$

we write $F$ as

> $$ F = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^ke^{-nx^2/2} dx  =  \int_{-\infty}^{0} x^ke^{-nx^2/2} dx + \int_{0}^{\infty} x^ke^{-nx^2/2} dx.  $$
>
> $$\implies I = (-1)^k\,\int_{0}^{\infty} t^k e^{-nt^2/2} dt + \int_{0}^{\infty} x^ke^{-nx^2/2} dx. $$

The last two integrals can be evaluated using the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and the change of variables $u=nx^2$.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thanks a lot.  Nice.

Comment: @Jeff: You are very welcome.